# What are the diode and two capacitors doing in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, batteries, diodes, ground

I have an existing circuit from a working design that I am trying to understand in order to apply the understanding to a different circuit I'm building.

[image: Schematic of the circuit fragment]

[image]

We can reduce the scenario to basically two ICs and a handful of discrete components. The first IC is a CPLD, and it is powered by 3.3V from the computer that it is installed in. The second IC is SRAM, and it is powered directly from a 3V coin cell battery. The two chips talk to each other through a couple control signals and a parallel data bus, and I think we can assume for the purposes of this question that the small voltage difference between the two of them is within tolerances for the signals.

The part I am struggling to understand is that the ground connection between the two of them is ultimately shared, but the ground of the SRAM is passed through a circuit involving two capacitors in parallel and a diode between them, before connecting to the shared ground.

My question is- what could that part of the circuit be doing? I'm guessing that it is in some way trying to isolate the ground of the SRAM, possibly to prevent power leakage between the two sides of the circuit. But I'm not sure, and I'm especially unsure of what the diode there is doing.

Comment: Where is the 3V3 ground connected to? Does the SRAM ground 'float'. One or other must or the cct does nothing.

Comment: IF the feed was from 3V3 to battery it would charge the. Battery. |. If from 3V3 to 3V it would power the SRAM usually and the 3V battery is a backup. It is "almost certain " that this is what happens. You may have swapped ground and supply labels.

Comment: You're right.... I swapped some things around. Not sure how (guess it was late) but things make a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certain that the diode is from 3V3 to 3V.

In that position it would power the SRAM usually and the 3V battery is a backup.

You may have swapped ground and supply labels.

High quality [tm] corrected diagram :-)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it’s a drawing error for Vbackup with an ultracap

Comment: @tony Probably a non rechargeable battery backup given the series battery diode

Comment: You're totally right - not sure how I screwed that up so bad. The circuit makes so much more sense now! :)

Comment: if you correct it , it might make sense, otherwise not